# Why does my code return 0 for the minimum no matter what the actual minimum is?

Tags: python

I am writing a piece of code for an assignment for class that is supposed to find the minimum and maximum when given a string. This is the code I have written so far:

```
 def find_min_and_max(values):
    '''(string) -> None

    '''
    mmin = 0
    mmax = 0
    if values == '': 
            print('There is no min or max')
            return None
    for value in values:
        if len(values) == 1: 
            mmax = value
            mmin = value
        if value > str(mmax): 
            mmax = value
        if value < str(mmin): 
            mmin = value

 print('The minimum value is ' + str(mmin)) 
 print('The maximum value is ' + str(mmax))
 return None
```

When I run it on the shell, this is the answer I receive:

">>> find_min_and_max('132475689')

"The minimum value is 0"

"The maximum value is 9""

Why am I getting minimum 0? This happens for whatever string of numbers for the parameter, I enter. Thanks.

Comment: Do you actually want to do a string compare? Or did you intend to compare ints?

Comment: problem#2, mmin starts at 0

Comment: The minimum isn't always 0. Try `find_min_and_max('$132475689')`. Or `find_min_and_max('132 475 689')`.

Answer (score 1):

Your logic is right in some way, but you have some mistakes.

The comparison `len(values) == 1` is good, but can be out of the `for`, because you just have to check it once.

You are trying to find the max and the min value, so you must compare integers, not strings. This `map(int,values)` creates a generator mapping your string in a list of integers so as to iterate. Than you can compare each value inside the `for`.

Answering your question: You are getting the `0` because the first comparison inside your `for`. As I said, you just have to do this once.

```
import math

def find_min_and_max(values):
    '''(string) -> None 

    '''
    mmin = math.inf
    mmax = -math.inf
    if values == '': 
            print('There is no min or max')
            return
    if len(values) == 1:
        mmax = values
        mmin = values
    for value in map(int,values):
        if value > mmax: 
            mmax = value
        if value < mmin: 
            mmin = value

    print('The minimum value is ' + str(mmin)) 
    print('The maximum value is ' + str(mmax))
```

The code above compare only numbers. If your string have another character, it won't work. So you may compare the code of the character in ASCII table. Just do:

```
import math

def find_min_and_max(values):
    '''(string) -> None 

    '''
    mmin = '~'
    mmax = ' '
    if values == '': 
            print('There is no min or max')
            return
    if len(values) == 1:
        mmax = values
        mmin = values
    for value in values:
        if ord(value) > ord(mmax): 
            mmax = value
        if ord(value) < ord(mmin): 
            mmin = value

    print('The minimum value is ' + str(mmin)) 
    print('The maximum value is ' + str(mmax))
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume that the string can only contain numeric values and you want to compare them by the numeric value.

Here is a quick and easy way of achieving the same results:

```
def find_min_and_max(values):
    if values == '': 
        print('There is no min or max')
        return None
```

Convert everything to a list of integers

```
    int_values = [int(x) for x in values]
```

Use the built-in functions for finding min and max

```
    print(f"The minimum value is {min(int_values)}") 
    print(f"The maximum value is {max(int_values)}")
    return None
find_min_and_max('132475689')
# The minimum value is 1
# The maximum value is 9
```

To get your code working, just set `mmin` to a large value to start. Since you are only looking at one digit at a time, 9 will work, or see @abarnert for large string values (you start your `mmin` value at the highest value possible so that the first value lower overwrites the variable):

```
 def find_min_and_max(values):
    '''(string) -> None

    '''
    mmin = 9
    mmax = 0
    if values == '': 
            print('There is no min or max')
            return None
    for value in values:
        if len(values) == 1: 
            mmax = value
            mmin = value
        if value > str(mmax): 
            mmax = value
        if value < str(mmin): 
            mmin = value

    print('The minimum value is ' + str(mmin)) 
    print('The maximum value is ' + str(mmax))
    return None
find_min_and_max('132475689')

# The minimum value is 1
# The maximum value is 9
```

However, there are some odd choices in your code. For example, you are comparing the numbers as strings rather than integers. It works...just odd. I'd convert the string to an int rather than the int to a string. The special case handling of if there is only one value isn't needed.

By the way, pdb (Python debugger) or [Python Tutor](http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html#code=def%20find_min_and_max%28values%29%3A%0A%20%20%20%20'''%28string%29%20-%3E%20None%0A%0A%20%20%20%20'''%0A%20%20%20%20mmin%20%3D%200%0A%20%20%20%20mmax%20%3D%200%0A%20%20%20%20if%20values%20%3D%3D%20''%3A%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20print%28'There%20is%20no%20min%20or%20max'%29%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20None%0A%20%20%20%20for%20value%20in%20values%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20len%28values%29%20%3D%3D%201%3A%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20mmax%20%3D%20value%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20mmin%20%3D%20value%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20value%20%3E%20str%28mmax%29%3A%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20mmax%20%3D%20value%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20value%20%3C%20str%28mmin%29%3A%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20mmin%20%3D%20value%0A%0A%20%20%20%20print%28'The%20minimum%20value%20is%20'%20%2B%20str%28mmin%29%29%20%0A%20%20%20%20print%28'The%20maximum%20value%20is%20'%20%2B%20str%28mmax%29%29%0A%20%20%20%20return%20None%0A%0Afind_min_and_max%28'132475689'%29&cumulative=false&curInstr=47&heapPrimitives=nevernest&mode=display&origin=opt-frontend.js&py=3&rawInputLstJSON=%5B%5D&textReferences=false) which lets you visualize your code are good resources for understanding what's going on inside your program.

Comment: A suitable large value to compare strings to might be `'\U001000ff'` for Python 3 or `\xff` for Python 2.